# Radio Button and text view layout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, radio-button

I want my Text view on the left side of my layout and radio button on the right side. But when I run my code it shows both textview and radiobutton on right side only. 
Following is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**use linear layout with weight property its also helps in device design compatibility**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="asfafasf"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbAnswer1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAnswer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbAnswer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:llayout_toRightOf="@+id/tvAnswer1"

            />
```

It will do, that your radio button be at right of the TextView.